# Display four or more authors instead of “et al.”

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I'm trying to write a bibliography in which many authors of a book appears in this format:

> Author1, Author2, Author3 and Author4

So, I'm using here biblatex this way:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
```

.bib file

```
@book{atl1,
    label       = {Tavares et al.},
    author      = {Cristopher Tavares and Kirk Fertitta and Brent Rector and Chris Sells},
    title       = {ATL Internals},
    subtitle    = {Working with ATL 8},
    edition     = {2},
    publisher   = {Addison-Wesley Professional},
    date        = {2006-07-15},
    totalpages  = {888}
    }
```

But the output of this is

> Cristopher Tavares and al.

.tex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,french]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel} \usepackage{csquotes}% recommended in output (biblatex) 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{bibli.bib} 
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\end{document}
```

How do I to deal with this, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write in your preamble

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, maxnames=4]{biblatex}
```

4 or more if you wish. There is also a `minnames` key which indicates the number of names that appear before `et alii` (default is 1). These values can be set independently for citations and the bibliography, with `maxbibnames`, `minbibnames`, `maxcitenames` and `mincitenames` (see p. 46 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

Answer (score 2):

The `maxnames` option is what you're looking for:

```
\usepackage[maxnames=100,backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
```